# Reboot or select proper boot device error in Windows

Tags: windows, boot

I have watched many videos on how to this, but didn't find any way to do this in gigabyte motherboard. Please help me, fast, i cant even open my PC.

Comment: This error message is produced by BIOS boot procedure and it means that the device which is set in your BIOS settings as bootable have no valid boot block. Possible reasons: incorrect boot device is set in the BIOS settings, incorrect boot mode (MBR/UEFI) is set, bootblock is damaged. Check first 2 reasons firstly.

Comment: I have used easybcd and add an empty drive in boot menu. I think that's the reason.

Comment: Maybe. When the error message in boot block is equal to BIOS's error message (close to impossible, the message differs). Or when bootblock does not boot and return the execution back to BIOS (possible).

Comment: So what do u recommend me to do?

Comment: Try to rebuild BCD and restore bootblocks (both device and partition ones - /fixmbr and /fixboot).

Comment: How to do this? I can't even open my PC.

Comment: You must use bootable CD/flashdrive (may use OS installation disk). One-time bootable device selection - F8 on the POST screen.